# Multiple joins on same table SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have one table [item] supposed to have thousands of records :

```
    ID  ItemNo  DepartDate  Country Item    Amount  
    1       1   2016-01-01  France  HOTEL   100 
    1       2   2016-01-01  France  HOTEL   150
    1       3   2016-01-01  France  MEALS   150
    2       1   2016-02-01  England HoTEL   150
    2       1   2016-02-01  England MEALS   200
    2       1   2016-02-02  England MEALS   200
    2       1   2016-02-02  WALES   MEALS   200
```

I want the result to count on number of Hotel, meal based on distinct departDate :

```
    Country hotelCount  mealCount
    France  1             1
    England 1             2
    WALES   0             1 


    Select i.Country, Count(distinct iHotel.DepartDate) as hotelCount, Count(distinct iMeal.DepartDate) as mealCount
    FROm item i
    left join item iHotel on i.id = v.id and i.Country =iHotel.Country 
    left join item iMeal  on i.id = iMeal .id and i.Country =iMeal .Country 
    where i.Country is not null
    group by i.country
```

But it does not work for thousands of records as it always causes time out issue. Any kind help ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: mysql or sql-server - pick one.

Comment: What indexes do you have on the table?

Comment: I'm using sql server,  the index is id,  id and departDate,  id and itemno.

Answer (score 0):

In this query, you don't do anything to separate meal and hotel :

```
Select i.Country, Count(distinct iHotel.DepartDate) as hotelCount, Count(distinct iMeal.DepartDate) as mealCount
    FROm item i
    left join item iHotel on i.id = v.id and i.Country =iHotel.Country 
    left join item iMeal  on i.id = iMeal .id and i.Country =iMeal .Country 
    where i.Country is not null
    group by i.country
```

I am not very happy with this query and sql Fiddle doesn't work again :

```
Select i.Country, MAX(coalesce(H.CT,0)) as hotelCount  , MAX(coalesce(M.CT,0)) as mealCount
    FROM item i
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT COUNT(*) as CT,Country, Item
       FROM item 
         WHERE item = 'HOTEL' GROUP BY Country, Item) H
      ON H.Country = i.Country AND i.Item = H.item
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT COUNT(*) as CT,Country, Item
         FROM item
          WHERE item = 'MEALS' GROUP BY Country, Item) M
      ON M.Country = i.Country AND i.Item = M.item
    GROUP BY i.Country
```